# using direct call from a widget in version 2.1 and 2.2

Tags: android, android-widget

I wrote a widget that can call numbers directly with one click. It works on the emulator, and it used to work on my nexus one when it had Android 2.1. Now I got the update, and the widget stopped working. I am using Intent.ACTION_CALL, and android.permission.CALL_PHONE. If I change to Intent.ACTION_DIAL it works, and the same code works from an activity. It is the combination of an app widget and the call action. I don't see any error. Does anyone know if it is not possible, and if so, how? Are there many cases the emulator is different than the cell phones, concerning the permission aspects?

The numbers are all regular, not 911 or something.

Comment: Do you see anything in LogCat when you try tapping on your app widget that would give you a clue as to why it stopped working? Also, if it worked on your Nexus One with 2.1 and now stops working with the Nexus One with 2.2, I fail to see how the emulator comes into the picture.

Comment: The 2.2 emulator works, so I don't think its supposed to be improved security check added in 2.2.

Comment: I don't see anything in the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it is not possible. The docs did mention changes might happen to this intent.